# JPA Postgres Function getting "<unnamed portal 4>" after execte()

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I am performing an operation to get results from StoredProcedureQuery and getting "<unnamed portal 4>" please help me to get results from "<unnamed portal 4>" .

I am using below tech stack

Java 8,
Spring Boot 2,
JPA,
Postgres

Answer (score 1):

I have missed the @Transactional annotation, Since we have insert statements inside function